# Kubo Formula for DC conductivity

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body

The frequency dependent electric conductivity in the Kubo formalism is given as: $\sigma^{\alpha \beta}(r,r^{'},w)=\frac{ie^2}{w}\Pi_{\alpha \beta}^{R}(r,r^{'},w) + \frac{e^2n(r)}{wm}\delta(r-r^{'})\delta_{\alpha \beta}$. where $\Pi^{R}_{\alpha \beta}(rt,r^{'}t^{'})=-i\theta(t-t^{'})\langle[J_0^{\alpha}(r,t),J_0^{\beta}(r^{'},t^{'})] \rangle_0$ is the retarted current current correlation function in time and $\Pi^{R}_{\alpha \beta}(r,r^{'},w)$ is the fourier transform of the above function. The DC conductivity is found in the limit $w \rightarrow 0$. I dont understand how the DC conductivity is given as the real part of $\frac{ie^2}{w}\Pi_{\alpha \beta}^{R}(r,r^{'},w)$ i.e.
$\sigma_{DC}=Re(\frac{ie^2}{w}\Pi_{\alpha \beta}^{R}(r,r^{'},w))$.

The reference is "Introduction to Many-Body Theory in Condensed Matter Physics" by Henrik Bruus and Karsten Flensburg, chapter 6 on linear response theory.